# Clash of clans spectator issue

Tags: clash-of-clans

There are 21 members in MY clan. I'm the leader. I have been the leader of this clan for a year and never left the clan. But I still can not participate in the league war. 
One of my co-leaders started a league war and it is only allowing 15 members in the war and they can't be exchanged for any other people including me. I have been in this clan the whole time so I couldn't have been in a different clan or anything. Why can I not be in the war? Its telling me I'm a spectator. I am high enough rank as well so it doesn't make sense.... please help. Thank you!!

Comment: No. I dont think people get what I'm saying I've been the leader of this clandestine for a year and never left how can I not participate in the league war??? @Bassie-c

Comment: If you feel this is a different question, then make clear how it is a different. I see you have already added some additional info, however, you need to make really clear how this is a different question and how answers on the other post did not satisfy your question. Since you didn't even mention this possible duplicate in your post, I assumed you'd never even read the answers that were given on it, so it was highly likely one of them provided an answer for you, removing the need for a separate question.

Comment: I read the answers I have been asking this question none of those answers are helping the only other way to word my question would have to be in a different language. I dont think you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I have 21 clan members therefore there should be 20 people allowed in the war. We started it with only 15 people but I can't put myself in the war even though I'm the leader of the clan. I couldn't have been on another war I'm the leader of my own clan so those answers do not answer my question.